# How do I point vscode to the right header files?

Tags: c++, c, oop, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use a sample cpp program from my university for a Roboteq motor controller. It comes with some headerfiles, but vscode will not recognize them. When trying to compile the program, I get the output:

```
C:\Users\joost\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLEV7F8.o: In function `main':
c:/Users/joost/Documents/School shit/OOP/Roboteq/sample.cpp:14: undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::RoboteqDevice()'
c:/Users/joost/Documents/School shit/OOP/Roboteq/sample.cpp:15: undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::Connect(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
c:/Users/joost/Documents/School shit/OOP/Roboteq/sample.cpp:24: undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::SetConfig(int, int, int)'
c:/Users/joost/Documents/School shit/OOP/Roboteq/sample.cpp:30: undefined reference to `sleepms(int)'
c:/Users/joost/Documents/School shit/OOP/Roboteq/sample.cpp:34: undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::GetConfig(int, int, int&)'
c:/Users/joost/Documents/School shit/OOP/Roboteq/sample.cpp:40: undefined reference to `sleepms(int)'
c:/Users/joost/Documents/School shit/OOP/Roboteq/sample.cpp:43: undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::GetValue(int, int, int&)'
c:/Users/joost/Documents/School shit/OOP/Roboteq/sample.cpp:49: undefined reference to `sleepms(int)'
c:/Users/joost/Documents/School shit/OOP/Roboteq/sample.cpp:52: undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::SetCommand(int, int, int)'
c:/Users/joost/Documents/School shit/OOP/Roboteq/sample.cpp:57: undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::Disconnect()'
c:/Users/joost/Documents/School shit/OOP/Roboteq/sample.cpp:14: undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::~RoboteqDevice()'
c:/Users/joost/Documents/School shit/OOP/Roboteq/sample.cpp:14: undefined reference to `RoboteqDevice::~RoboteqDevice()'
```

In tasks.json I have added `-I${workspaceFolder}` to the args, and in `c_cpp_properties.json` I have added the path to the project folder to `includePath`. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: The problem is not with header files. Did you link the library?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) answer your question?

Comment: You edit your `tasks.json` file to add the additional linker settings. `-L` is the folder of the library `-l` is the library

Comment: If you have more than 1 cpp file in your project perhaps you did not modify your tasks.json to support that. The default setting builds only the active file.

Comment: @drescherjm the library does come with one cpp file, how would I modify the tasks.json to include that?